# sql server Invalid column error

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a problem in trigger

```
create trigger urunguncelle on stok_yedek for insert 
as begin
   declare @adi nchar(100)
   set @adi=[Stok Adı (1852)]
   insert into deneme (adi) values (@adi)
end
```

Error message is:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure urunguncelle, Line 5 Invalid
>   column name 'Stok Adı (1852)'.

But table has been Stok Adı (1852)

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish? The line `set @adi=[Stok Adı (1852)]` doesnt select anything that could be set to `@adi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bearing in mind that the [`inserted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) pseudo-table that is present in triggers can contain *multiple* rows (and so assigning anything to a scalar variable is an instant mistake), are you perhaps looking for this:

```
create trigger urunguncelle on stok_yedek for insert 
as begin
   insert into deneme (adi)
   select [Stok Adı (1852)] from inserted
end
```